# Tableau 9.3 need to match values to reference table

Tags: lookup, tableau-api

Ok. So, I received a data set that lists 'STATE' as a value

```
STATE
  1
  4
  3
 ...
```

The set came with a reference table  that has the fifty 'STATES' listed by name

```
 STATE
Alabama
Alaska
Arizona
Arkansas
  ...
```

The goal is to replace the numeric representations for States in the first table with the proper State name found in the reference table.

I thought that I could create calculated field like using a lookup statement like

`LOOKUP(ATTR([State (reference)].[State]),(FIRST() + SUM(STATE (data).[State]))`

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

First drag the State field to the dimensions section of the data pane to convert it to a discrete (blue) dimension.

Then you can either:

- a. Right click on the State field and edit the aliases for that
  field, i.e. to type the name for each State. Tableau will display the
  aliases even though the data source provides numeric values.
- OR b.
  If your reference table has a column with the numeric code in it, and
  if the reference table is in the same database or Excel file, then
  you can edit the data source to JOIN the reference table and get the
  state names provided by the data source (avoiding typing in the
  aliases)
- OR c. If your reference table has the code column, but
  cannot exist in the database or Excel file, then you can get a
  similar effect to the JOIN above using Tableau's data blending feature.